# Write $M^+=\{n \in M: n>0\}.$ Is $M^+$ non-empty? Explain.

Tags: number-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be two positive integers and $M$ the set of all integer linear combinations of $a$ and $b$. Write $M^+=\{n \in M: n>0\}.$ Is $M^+$ non-empty? Explain.

Just to provide more detail $n=au+bv$ where $u,v \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I believe that $M^+$ is non-empty. But how would I prove this? Would I just show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an example is perfectly fine and $a=a\cdot 1+b\cdot0$ would suffice. But you don't need that $a$ and $b$ are positive, just that one of them is nonzero, because, in this case,
$$
0<a^2+b^2=a\cdot a+b\cdot b\in M^+
$$

Answer (score 1):

The example will be enough: $a, b$ are positive and belong to $M^+$.

Comment: $4(6)+3(-6)=1$ is a sufficient example?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to prove that $M^+$ is non-empty, it will be enough to find an element that belongs to this set. THat is a perfectly fine proof.

Comment: Do you think the example I posted under @Leon answer would be enough?

Comment: No, you need to find an example that works no matter what $a$ and $b$ are. But you can take $4a+3b$, if you like.